# Single-page module for Yii2

Tags: php, ember.js, yii2

What is the best way to create a single page module for Yii2?

For example using Ember, I will have index.html and assets folder to publish.

I see two ways, one would be to just put the application under web accessible folder, it will work fine.
But what if i want to check access to the application using existing RBAC?

Another way would be to create a module and in default controller have something like

`return $this->renderFile('@path/to/index.html');`

And load all assets with Asset Bundle.

The problem with this approach is that i will not know the folder where assets will be loaded (it can be solved with afterCopy callback or something, but all this doesn't look nice at all).

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly it is a personal choice technique, since control RBAC is manageable level `action` and does not pose any problem. Once the controller is easy applicarre your organization's access control using a suitable configuration of the `Access Control filter`.

Alternatively, the fact of creating a module appropriately for these purposes makes it all the better organized and, precisely, modular, beyond the greater complexity in the creation of the various parts in play (module, asset, cofig / main.php) yii2 handles very well and automatically the assets and necessariio not know a priori in the name of the folder where I finish the specific assets (Yii2 find what they need).

However if this is not a 'module' with reusable application characteristics I would opt for the first solution